# Unable to mock webservice client using mockito

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mocking, mockito, spring-test

I am testing a spring mvc controller which gets a webservice client autowired and its been mocked vai mockito. But the mocking is not working. Invoking "verify(stuClient, times(1)).getAllStudents(sAndPCommand);" in test returns

```
Wanted but not invoked:

stuClient.getAllStudents(
    com.xyz.crudserviceclient.utilitybeans.SortablePagedCommand@3028e50e
);
-> at com.xyz.controllers.StudentControllerTest.testGetHomePage(StudentControllerTest.java:101)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.xyz.controllers.StudentControllerTest.testGetHomePage(StudentControllerTest.java:101).....
```

Below is my controller method in test:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHomePage.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView getHomePage(@RequestParam(value = "first", required = false) Integer first,
      @RequestParam(value = "max", required = false) Integer max, @RequestParam(value = "sortBy",
      required = false) String sortBy,
      @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", required = false) String sortDir) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");

    SortablePagedCommand sortablePagedCommand = new SortablePagedCommand();
    sortablePagedCommand.setFirst(first);
    sortablePagedCommand.setMax(max);
    sortablePagedCommand.setSort(sortBy);
    sortablePagedCommand.setSortDir(sortDir);

    PagedResult<StudentBean> students = studentServiceClient.getAllStudents(sortablePagedCommand);
    List<StudentBean> studentList = students.getItems();

    int noOfRecords = students.getUnfilteredItems();
    int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / max);

    mav.addObject("sortByField", sortBy);
    mav.addObject("sortDirField", sortDir);
    mav.addObject("studentList", studentList);
    mav.addObject("noOfPages", noOfPages);
    mav.addObject("currentPage", first);

    return mav;
  }
```

And below is my test Class:

```
package com.xyz.controllers;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.xyz.crudserviceclient.beans.StudentBean;
import com.xyz.crudserviceclient.client.StudentServiceClient;
import com.xyz.crudserviceclient.utilitybeans.PagedResult;
import com.xyz.crudserviceclient.utilitybeans.SortablePagedCommand;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class StudentControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @InjectMocks
    private StudentController controller;
    @Mock
    private StudentServiceClient stuClient;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
        Mockito.reset(stuClient);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void testGetHomePage() throws Exception {
        StudentBean sb1 = new StudentBean();
        sb1.setFirstName("Sai");
        sb1.setLastName("Palaparthi");
        sb1.setGender("Male");
        sb1.setDOB(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        sb1.setEmail("v.p@gmail.com");
        sb1.setMobileNumber("8121157247");
        sb1.setAddress("Huda");
        sb1.setCourses(Arrays.asList("Math", "Chem"));

        StudentBean sb2 = new StudentBean();
        sb2.setFirstName("Viswanath");
        sb2.setLastName("Palaparthi");
        sb2.setGender("Male");
        sb2.setDOB(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        sb2.setEmail("v.p@gmail.com");
        sb2.setMobileNumber("8121157248");
        sb2.setAddress("Huda");
        sb2.setCourses(Arrays.asList("Math"));

        PagedResult<StudentBean> pResult = new PagedResult<StudentBean>(
                Arrays.asList(sb1, sb2), 2);
        pResult.setFirst(0);
        pResult.setUnfilteredItems(2);

        Integer first = 0;
        Integer max = 5;
        String sortBy = "firstname";
        String sortDir = "asc";

        SortablePagedCommand sAndPCommand = new SortablePagedCommand();
        sAndPCommand.setFirst(first);
        sAndPCommand.setMax(max);
        sAndPCommand.setSort(sortBy);
        sAndPCommand.setSortDir(sortDir);
        Mockito.when(stuClient.getAllStudents(sAndPCommand))
                .thenReturn(pResult);

        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/getHomePage.do").param("first", String.valueOf(first))
                        .param("max", String.valueOf(max))
                        .param("sortBy", sortBy)
                        .param("sortDirection", sortDir))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("home"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/jsps/home.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("sortByField", is(sortBy)))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("sortDirField", is(sortDir)))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("noOfPages", 1))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("currentPage", is(first)))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("studentList", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(
                        model().attribute(
                                "studentList",
                                hasItem(allOf(
                                        hasProperty("firstName", is("Sai")),
                                        hasProperty("lastName",
                                                is("Palaparthi")),
                                        hasProperty("gender", is("Male")),
                                        hasProperty(
                                                "dob",
                                                is(new Date(System
                                                        .currentTimeMillis()))),
                                        hasProperty("email",
                                                is("v.p@gmail.com")),
                                        hasProperty("mobileNumber",
                                                is("8121157247")),
                                        hasProperty("address", is("Huda")),
                                        hasProperty("courses",
                                                hasItems("Math", "Chem"))))))
                .andExpect(
                        model().attribute(
                                "studentList",
                                hasItem(allOf(
                                        hasProperty("firstName",
                                                is("Viswanath")),
                                        hasProperty("lastName",
                                                is("Palaparthi")),
                                        hasProperty("gender", is("Male")),
                                        hasProperty(
                                                "dob",
                                                is(new Date(System
                                                        .currentTimeMillis()))),
                                        hasProperty("email",
                                                is("v.p@gmail.com")),
                                        hasProperty("mobileNumber",
                                                is("8121157248")),
                                        hasProperty("address", is("Huda")),
                                        hasProperty("courses", hasItems("Math"))))));

        verify(stuClient, times(1)).getAllStudents(sAndPCommand);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(stuClient);

    }
}
```

Comment: btw the argument of the call of `mockMvc.perform(/*...*/)` is way too complex. In such a test you should focus on the fact that the correct list is passed to the mock (probably using `Mockito.same`) and not the contents of the list and the properties of those elements.

Comment: You also don't need `Mockito.reset(stuClient);` as a mock is initialized for every test case and a newly initialized mock is reset per definition.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all wrong - this is obviously an integration test so why involve Mockito at all; additionally, you're injecting mocks into the controller field but your tests are not invoking the controller field - they are interacting with the controller bean from your Spring context.

Take a look at [this excellent tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-mvc-test-tutorial/), especially the unit test part.

To sum it up, your test setup needs to change, you don't need any of the annotations and also you have to use standalone MockMvc setup for your controller:

```
public class StudentControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private StudentController controller;

    @Mock
    private StudentServiceClient stuClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        Mockito.reset(stuClient);
    }
```